# Inserting set of controls at runtime is extremely slow

Tags: delphi, user-interface, controls, delphi-xe

We have a point-of-sale application and in this application we have a scrollbox container. If the seller selects a product, then a new product row is created and inserted into the scrollbox. The product row component is a frame - textboxes, buttons and labels in it.

But here's a little problem by inserting this product row control into the scrollbox at runtime. It's slow. I can see how selecting product draws edittext components slowly into the scrollbox.

I tried to set the components' `visibility` to false before `ScrollBox.InsertControl` and enabling it after, but it doesn't help speed up things very much. Also I read about DisableAlign/EnableAlign thing, but I don't know exactly where I have to put this line of code.

How can I speed up inserting this custom component into the form's scrollbox container?

Comment: Showing us the code you are using will go a long way towards getting a sensible answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TScrollBox doesn't have BeginUpdate/EndUpdate, but [you can get the same effect](http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.vcl.components.using.win32/200511/051122635.html) using WM_SETREDRAW messages.  I would probably avoid more heavy handed methods like [LockWindowUpdate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/22/1742084.aspx).

```
  SendMessage(ScrollBox1.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0);
  try
    // add controls to scrollbox
    // set scrollbox height
  finally
    SendMessage(ScrollBox1.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0);
    RedrawWindow(ScrollBox1.Handle, nil, 0, RDW_ERASE or RDW_INVALIDATE or RDW_FRAME or RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a control adding to a container takes very little time. There's a high probability this has something to do with the creation of the control rather the insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling screen updates when adding controls and enable screen update when done in a try-finally routine. Then the screen doesn't have to update for each separate control but just once, when all controls are placed.