# How to align controls left and top without fixed width?

Tags: delphi, alignment, controls, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have 6 RichEdit controls in ScrollBox. They need to be aligned left in sequence from top to bottom, but I need width to be not fixed, so I can use scroll bar to scroll to see full text, when text length goes beyond ScrollBox width.

If I set:

```
RichEdit1.Align := alTop;
RichEdit2.Align := alTop;
RichEdit3.Align := alTop;
RichEdit4.Align := alTop;
RichEdit5.Align := alTop;
RichEdit6.Align := alTop;
```

they align perfectly and stay fixed in design so  can't move them accidentally, but the width gets fixed. Not good.

If I align them manually, then they are not fixed when clicking on them and can be moved and I need to re-arrange all the time. Annoying.

The picture show on top all RichEdits with Align = alTop and width is fixed to ScrollBox width. 
Bottom example is with manual alignment of all RichEdits that width can go beyond ScrollBox's width, but they can be moved around in design:

[image]

So, I would like to get them fixed to left, top as does alTop, but not to fix the width. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can prevent accidental moving of components by menu item Edit - Lock Controls once you have them correctly placed.

Comment: Looking for a level of alTop alignment, but not strict for width. Yes, so they are locked in design and stay aligned in runtime.

Comment: Using `Align = alTop` fixes the width to the parent.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Exactly! I need to have them aligned Top and Left as alTop does, but not fixed width - the width of RichEdit, not parent. As parent is ScrollBox it will show horizontal Scrollbar when RichEdit's width is beyond ScrollBox's width.

Comment: Yeah, I get what you are aiming at, but there's unfortunately no such thing as `alTop` without fixing the width to he width of the parent. Locking the controls once properly placed, and considering the points @Jerry brought up, is still the best you can do, IMO.

Comment: Shame. I stopped using Lock Controls it was buggy in XE7 and now in 10.1 Berlin is still buggy.

Comment: What would your solution be for many other controls in different parts of your application? Such as buttons, checkboxes, etc.... Personally I would prefer to implement a new property on `TWinControl` ancestor `LockChildren`.

Comment: Or it would be nice to be able to set this with a combination of Align, Anchors or some other property, to allow more flexible positioning and locking of controls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At design time use `Align = alTop`. Then, at runtime (e,g, `OnCreate` of form) set `Align := alNone`, and change the width as you like.

Comment: That's pretty clever, I guess. It would work like I needed it to.

Comment: This is certainly how I would do it in a similar situation, that's why I reopened my answer.

Comment: Will need to test how much time the changing in OnCreate would take for 12 ScrollBoxes I have. I don't have very good experience with changing alignment in runtime, it either takes a while or when changing one control all other start moving around before the process of complete change is done...

Comment: @MikeTorrettinni yes, my experience is that it will be slow.  See this question on how to mimic a BeginUpdate/EndUpdate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196752/inserting-set-of-controls-at-runtime-is-extremely-slow

Comment: @JohnEasley Thank you, will make sure I refer to the linked answer if needed.

Answer (score 3):

If preventing accidental moving is your goal, I see two solutions.

**Use Delphi's "Lock Controls" option**

`Edit > Lock Controls`, but this is a temporary solution which is not saved, and upon closing / re-opening, it will be disabled again.

**Align them all inside of a panel**

And then make that panel to the width you need. However this still wouldn't prevent you from accidentally moving the panel - just the edit controls. And even then, you're still able to re-arrange aligned controls - if you were to accidentally drag one beyond the edge of its neighbor.

Here's a sample DFM structure:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 340
  ClientWidth = 392
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ScrollBox1: TScrollBox
    Left = 24
    Top = 8
    Width = 329
    Height = 281
    TabOrder = 0
    object Panel1: TPanel
      Left = 3
      Top = 3
      Width = 500
      Height = 217
      TabOrder = 0
      object Edit1: TEdit
        Left = 1
        Top = 1
        Width = 498
        Height = 21
        Align = alTop
        TabOrder = 0
        Text = 'Edit1'
        ExplicitLeft = 40
        ExplicitTop = 48
        ExplicitWidth = 121
      end
      object Edit2: TEdit
        Left = 1
        Top = 22
        Width = 498
        Height = 21
        Align = alTop
        TabOrder = 1
        Text = 'Edit2'
        ExplicitLeft = 16
        ExplicitTop = 56
        ExplicitWidth = 121
      end
      object Edit3: TEdit
        Left = 1
        Top = 43
        Width = 498
        Height = 21
        Align = alTop
        TabOrder = 2
        Text = 'Edit3'
        ExplicitLeft = 40
        ExplicitTop = 96
        ExplicitWidth = 121
      end
      object Edit4: TEdit
        Left = 1
        Top = 64
        Width = 498
        Height = 21
        Align = alTop
        TabOrder = 3
        Text = 'Edit4'
        ExplicitLeft = 32
        ExplicitTop = 128
        ExplicitWidth = 121
      end
      object Edit5: TEdit
        Left = 1
        Top = 85
        Width = 498
        Height = 21
        Align = alTop
        TabOrder = 4
        Text = 'Edit5'
        ExplicitLeft = 56
        ExplicitTop = 160
        ExplicitWidth = 121
      end
      object Edit6: TEdit
        Left = 1
        Top = 106
        Width = 498
        Height = 21
        Align = alTop
        TabOrder = 5
        Text = 'Edit6'
        ExplicitLeft = 80
        ExplicitTop = 192
        ExplicitWidth = 121
      end
    end
  end
end
```

On another note, this has inspired me to investigate how I can implement a `LockChildren` Boolean property on the `TControl` level which, when enabled, prevents you from moving or sizing its child controls.

---

Actually, I just found an apparent bug in Delphi with the "Lock Controls" option. If you enable it on a form, then close and re-open the form, the controls are no longer locked. But at the same time, if you go to the "Edit" menu, the "Lock Controls" option appears as if it's still enabled (even though it isn't). I think I recall this bug waaaaaay back in Delphi 7, but I see it still on Delphi 10 Seattle.

**EDIT** I found the QC report still open:

http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=82764

Comment: This bug is the reason I don't use Lock Controls. When I switch it on a while later the corners of controls still appear locked (gray dots instead of blue - indicating locked controls) but I can move them around.

Comment: @Mike Which is why I provided you another solution.

Comment: Not sure how that solution would help. Sometimes they annoyingly move when I select them - so, they would move no matter in which parent they are, right? Rearrange is needed in any case, or am I missing something with Panel?

Comment: @Mike I guess I'm missing your point. "Rearrange is needed in any case" Then what's the problem? "Sometimes they annoyingly move when I select them" They shouldn't, not if they're aligned `alTop`.

Comment: Aha, now I see what you mean: put controls in Panel and align them all to alTop and resize panel as needed, beyond ScrollBox's width. Right?

Comment: @Mike Yes, see the DFM sample I added to my answer.

Comment: This could work, yes, because I regularly need to select one of the controls and the spacing between them (3) would not let me select panel very easily to move it around. Let me test a bit.

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).